# Trying to apply same count to each item within a loop

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, nested-loops

I'm creating a loop in WordPress for a fancybox gallery. This means that each group of images needs to have the same rel identifier (for example rel="gallery1").  But since this is a nested loop, in other words, it's part of another loop, I need the next group of images in the loop to have a rel identifier different from the ones before/after (ex. rel="gallery2", rel="gallery3", etc.).

I've tried putting  next the the word gallery, but it just loops and gives every object another number instead of keeping the same number for each item in the grouping.

I'm not sure if what I'm explaining is making sense. Here's a basic idea of what I'm trying to have.

```
{gallery of images 1}
<a href="image" rel="gallery1">
    <img src="path">
</a>
<a href="image" rel="gallery1">
    <img src="path">
</a>
<a href="image" rel=gallery1">
    <img src="path">
</a>

{gallery of images2 }
<a href="image" rel="gallery2">
    <img src="path">
</a>
<a href="image rel="gallery2">
    <img src="path">
</a>
```

etc., etc.

The page itself is displaying a gallery of post thumbnails (featured images) from a custom post type. Clicking on a gallery item (representing one item in the custom post type) opens a Bootstrap modal window. In that modal window is a group of images related to that original gallery item (post type item). Clicking on one of those images opens a fancybox, but should only cycle through the images for that gallery item.  Crazy enough?

The rest of the page is working perfectly. Just having trouble with this rel numbering thing.

I had hesitated posting all the code because it's so long, but if it's helpful, here you go:

```
// Define the query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'pixieportfolio',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_portfolio_item',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'posts_per_page' => 999
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = 0;

// Carousel // ?>
<div id="featuredCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">

<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">

    <?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

        <li <?php if($count == 0){ echo 'class="active"';} ?> data-target="#featuredCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count++; ?>"></li>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php $count = 0;

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $count++;
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'pp-home-portfolio' );
        $url = $thumb['0'];
        $values = get_field('tech_choices');
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag');
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $caption = get_field('caption', '');
        $client =  get_field('client', '');
        $project_url = get_field('project_url', '');
        $date = get_field('date', ''); ?>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="item <?php if ($count == 1) { echo 'active';} ?>" data-slide-number="<?php echo $count++; ?>" id="<? the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="item-image" style="background-image: url(<?=$url?>);" title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>

        <div class="project-details">
            <div class="project-detail-border shadow-effect"></div>
            <div class="project-detail">
                 <div class="top-detail">
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <div class="short-description">
                         <?php $content = get_the_content();
                            echo wp_trim_words( $content , '20' );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table project">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" class="fifty">
                                 <?php $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'pixie-portfolio-categories', '', ', ', '' ) );
echo $terms_as_text;?>
                        </td>

                        <td valign="middle" class="fifty">
                            <?php if( $values ) {

                                if(in_array('WordPress', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-wordpress fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Wordpress"></i>
                                <?php } if(in_array('HTML-5', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="HTML-5"></i>
                                <?php } if(in_array('CSS-3', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="CSS-3"></i>
                                 <?php } if(in_array('Sportswear', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sportswear"></i>
                                <?php } if(in_array('Adobe', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Adobe"></i>
                                <?php } if(in_array('Code', $values )){ ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-code fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Code"></i>
                                 <?php } if(in_array('Ecommerce', $values )) { ?>
                                    <i class="fa fa-database fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="MySQL"></i>
                                     <?php }
                                } else {} ?>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="more-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <div class="view-project">View Project</div>
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                 </table>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal<?php echo $count; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal<?php echo $count; ?>Label">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h2 class="modal-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                    <span>
                        <?php if( $terms ): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php $icon = get_field('creative_icon', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id); echo $icon; ?>
                             <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="container-fluid">
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div>
                                     <p class="post-meta gallery-list">
                                         <?php if( $client ): ?>
                                         <span class="pixie-date">
                                            <span class="title">Client:</span> <?=$client?>
                                        </span>
                                        <?php endif;

                                        if ( $date ): ?>
                                         <span class="post-cats">
                                            <span class="title">Date:</span> <?=$date?>
                                        </span>
                                        <?php endif;

                                        if ( $values ) { ?>
                                         <span class="post-comments">
                                            <?php $values = get_field('tech_choices'); ?>
                                            <span class="title">Tech used in this project:</span>

                                            <?php if(in_array('WordPress', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-wordpress fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="WordPress"></i>
                                             <? }

                                            if(in_array('HTML-5', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-html5 fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="HTML5"></i>
                                            <? }

                                            if(in_array('CSS-3', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-css3 fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="CSS3"></i>
                                             <? }

                                            if(in_array('Sportswear', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Sportswear"></i>
                                             <? }

                                            if(in_array('Adobe', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Illustrator and/or Photoshop"></i>
                                            <? }

                                            if(in_array('Code', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-code fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="PHP, JQuery, etc."></i>
                                             <? }

                                            if(in_array('Ecommerce', $values )){ ?>
                                             <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="ECommerce"></i>
                                            <? }

                                            if(in_array('MySQL', $values )){ ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-database fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="MySQL"></i>
                                             <? } ?>
                                         </span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                     </p>
                                 </div>

                                <?php echo the_content(); ?>

                                <blockquote class="testimonial">

                                    QUOTE GOES HERE

                                </blockquote>
                             </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                 <div class="gallery">

                                <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'darwin-modal-main' );
                                $url = $thumb['0'];
                                $thumb2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
                                $url2 = $thumb2['0'];
                                $c = 0; ?>
                                <a href="<?=$url2?>" class="group" id="port_gal" rel="group<?php echo $c; ?>">
                                    <img src="<?=$url?>" width="300" height="300">
                                </a>

                                <?php $images = get_field('gallery_images');
                                     if( $images ) {
                                         foreach( $images as $image ) {
                                 ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large'] ?>" class="group" id="port_gal"  rel="group<?php echo $c; ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['darwin-modal-thumb'] ?>" alt="<?php $image['alt'] ?>" />
                                 </a>
                                         <?php }
                                    } ?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="website-button">

                                <?php if ( $project_url ): ?>
                                <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?=$project_url?>" target="_blank" role="button">Visit Website</a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing your actual loop would really help.

Comment: Each gallery group belongs to a different post?  How we know when a different gallery starts